# Min and Max of 2 of 2D array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 15
#define COLS 10

void find_elements(int mtr[ROWS][COLS], int a, int b, int *p1, int *p2);

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    int z, l;
    int arr[ROWS][COLS];
    int min;
    int max;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("numbers2.txt", "r");

    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("                                   Loaded Array                               \n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[i][j]);
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    do {
        printf("Enter row[1-15]:\n");
        scanf("%d", &z);
    } while ((z > 15) || (z < 1));

    do {
        printf("Enter column[1-10]:\n");
        scanf("%d", &l);
    } while ((l > 10 || (l < 1)));

     printf("------------------------------------\n");
     printf("The Max of Row %d is: %d\n", z, max);
     printf("The min of Column %d id: %d\n", l, min);

     find_elements(arr[ROWS][COLS], i, j, &min, &max);

     fclose(fp);
     return 0;
}

void find_elements(int mtr[ROWS][COLS], int a, int b, int *p1, int *p2) {
    int k;

    *p1 = mtr[a][0];
    *p2 = mtr[0][b];

    for (k = 1; k < COLS; k++) {
        if (*p1 <= mtr[a][k])
            *p1 = mtr[a][k];
    }

    for (k = 1; k < ROWS; k++) {
        if (*p2 >= mtr[k][b])
            *p2 = mtr[k][b];
    }
}
```

When I compile this program the following message appears:

```
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'find_elements'
 makes pointer from integer without a cast

[Note] expected 'int (*)[10]' but argument is of type 'int'
```

I am programming for about 3 months in C without a previous experience on programming before, so I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I need some help.
Thank you

Comment: Don't spam tags.  This is clearly not C#

Comment: `arr[ROWS][COLS]` is a single element.  `arr` is the address, which you need to pass, of the array.

Comment: @FiddlingBits No, `arr` _is_ the array.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments point out, in this line:

```
find_elements(arr[ROWS][COLS],i,j,&min,&max);
```

the first argument of the function call is a single `int`, and in fact an `int` that doesn't even exist, which invokes undefined behavior.

What you need to do is, pass the entire array to the function, like this:

```
find_elements(arr,i,j,&min,&max);
           // ^^^  just the array name
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 problems in your code:

- you should just pass `arr` as the first argument to `find_elements`,
- you should move the function call **before** the `printf`.
- you should pass `z` and `l` instead of `i` and `j`.
- why are row 0 and column 0 excluded from the search?

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 15
#define COLS 10

void find_elements(int mtr[ROWS][COLS], int a, int b, int *p1, int *p2);

int main(void) {
    int i, j, z, l;
    int arr[ROWS][COLS];
    int min, max;
    int c;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("numbers2.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open numbers2.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("                                   Loaded Array                               \n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[i][j]) != 1) {
                printf("invalid data\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);

    do {
        printf("Enter row[1-%d]:\n", ROWS);
        if (scanf("%d", &z) != 1) {
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            if (c == EOF) {
                printf("end of file\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("invalid entry\n");
            continue;
        }
    } while (z > ROWS || z < 1);

    do {
        printf("Enter column[1-%d]:\n", COLS);
        if (scanf("%d", &l) != 1) {
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            if (c == EOF) {
                printf("end of file\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("invalid entry\n");
            continue;
        }
    } while (l > COLS || l < 1);

     find_elements(arr, z, l, &min, &max);

     printf("------------------------------------\n");
     printf("The Max of Row %d is: %d\n", z, max);
     printf("The min of Column %d id: %d\n", l, min);

     return 0;
}

void find_elements(int mtr[ROWS][COLS], int a, int b, int *p1, int *p2) {
    int k;

    *p1 = mtr[a][0];
    *p2 = mtr[0][b];

    for (k = 1; k < COLS; k++) {
        if (*p1 < mtr[a][k])
            *p1 = mtr[a][k];
    }

    for (k = 1; k < ROWS; k++) {
        if (*p2 > mtr[k][b])
            *p2 = mtr[k][b];
    }
}
```